# Open close sidenav same button

Tags: html, css

I want to make this code responsive. It works on mobile perfectly, but when I click it on desktop, it does not work. I want to make that sidebar like wp.
When I am on mobile it will show like this code, but when I click it on a desktop, it will show like wp dashboard.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.sidebar-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
#sidebar-toggle-input {
  display: none;
}
#sidebar-toggle-input+label:before {
  content: "➡️";
}
#sidebar-toggle-input:checked + label:before {
  content: "❌"
}
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
#sidebar-toggle-input:checked ~ .sidebar {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="sidebar-toggle-input" />
<label class="sidebar-toggle" for="sidebar-toggle-input"></label>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
```

[Here is a Codepen of my project](https://codepen.io/Pogamar_YT/pen/NQaBqR)

Comment: Can you give us a runnable [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) please?

Comment: Okay. Have this bro https://codepen.io/Pogamar_YT/pen/NQaBqR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm sorry i don't think i get the question but i assume that's what you want
so here i add two different kind of nav and using media query i changed the display of each of them

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.sidebar-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
#sidebar-toggle-input {
  display: none;
}
#sidebar-toggle-input+label:before {
  content: "➡️";
}
#sidebar-toggle-input:checked + label:before {
  content: "❌"
}
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
#sidebar-toggle-input:checked ~ .sidebar {
  transform: none;
}
.sidebar ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.sidebar ul li{
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px){
  .sidebar-toggle-input, .sidebar-toggle{
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebar{
    width: 100px;
    transform: translatex(0);
  }
  .sidebar ul div li{
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebar ul div span{
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px){
.sidebar{
    width: 300px;
  }
  .sidebar ul div li{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="sidebar-toggle-input" />
<label class="sidebar-toggle" for="sidebar-toggle-input"></label>
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <div><span>&#9731;</span><li>home</li></div>
    <div><span>&#9731;</span><li>about</li></div>
    <div><span>&#9731;</span><li>contact</li></div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you brother.And Sorry again for my bad english

Comment: you mean this isn't what you want or it's not working like it should be !
try to open the snippet i provide in full screen then minimize it you should see the main nav disappeared and the icon and sidenavbar are now displayed
if you mean it works here but not in your code then check if you have any error
or provide it here so we can discussed here :)

Comment: i want to make the navbar like that. https://codepen.io/kazzkiq/pen/pvqvxO check out and change the screen size to understand what i really want to say you.

Comment: i updated the snippet above now this here is actually easier than the first solution i provided  but we kinda used more media! so here i used [for the sake of the example] two breakpoints which is 700px and 900px now when we are on a screen with width less than 700px we have the normal check which give us the sidebar but when go to 700px to 900px it kinda reduce the width of the sidebar and remove[display none] the links and leave the icons when we reach the 900px it's width become the largest and show us every content we have.
now you can edit this and add or remove stuff as you want it :)

Comment: check out the screenshot from my phone of your snippet https://www.datafilehost.com/d/825e4b5a

Comment: it works fine for me maybe this happened because browser support stuff but is this open on chrome? because it's has a nav which may affect your 100vh and what's your phone res!

Comment: But in my case it is not working. Yes it was opened by chrome. And my phone res is 720*1280

Comment: okay i think you didn't add the meta tags
here add this to your html inside the head tag
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">`

Comment: and copy the snippet i provide as it's and give it a try

Comment: Check this out https://www.datafilehost.com/d/8cae5afd not showing content plz help

Comment: so this site isn't made for walking each other step by step in each other projects it's just for answering a question which i did and deliver the idea so if you have another problem just ask a new question!!